# Не отрабатывают методы в лямбде

Tags: c++, com, lambda

```
while (cont)
{
    client.request(request).then([&](http_response response)
    {
        if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
        {                   
            buttonUp->click();              
        }
    }).wait();
}
```

`ButtonUp` - это указатель на `IHTMLElement`, полученный через COM объект `InternetExplorer.Application`. Ни один метод через него не отрабатывает, хотя ошибок никаких не возникает. Все отрабатывает тихо и спокойно, только клика не происходит.

За пределами лямбды отрабатывает на ура.

Comment: А внутрь лямбы попадает?

Comment: Попадает. И эту строку в отладке проходит без ошибок.

Comment: а метод `click()` можно выполнять в другом потоке, может в этом всё дело?

Comment: я только учусь поэтому с потоками пока не знаком.

Comment: @Abyx, я не хочу получить тот же результат. Мне нужно чтоб произошел клик. Вы можете подсказать в чем причина такого поведения? Куда копать?

Comment: Посмотрите, что возвращает `click`, вероятнее всего он завершается некорректно. Посмотрите почему, узнайте номер ошибки.

Comment: Сначала ничего не возвращал - писал что не вызван CoInitialize. Хотя я его вызываю в самом начале main. После того как добавил еще раз  CoInitialize внутрь лямбды появилась вот такая ошибка E_WRONG_THREAD The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. Я так понимаю, что нужно дать понять лямбде, что я уже вызывал CoInitialize, но я понятия не имею как это сделать.

Comment: ixSci,  спасибо за наводку. Решил проблему второй параметр  CoInitializeEx -  я указывал COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED, а надо было COINIT_MULTITHREAD